# Power MOSFET thermal calculations

Tags: thermal

For [this BSC0902NSI Infineon MOSFET](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/BSC0902NSI_Rev_2.1.pdf?folderId=db3a304313b8b5a60113cee8763b02d7&fileId=db3a30433072cd8f01308ea027703424) from page 3, I am trying to determine the size of heatsink required, temperature and heat dissipated. I have the following

1. Pd: 0.2 W
2. Ta: 35 °C
3. Theeta_jc: 20 °C/W - The datasheet has two jc, top and bottom. I chose the top since that is where I would placing the heatsink, because the bottom will have a copper pour of 6 x 6 cm.

Is Tsa and Tj calculated as

1. Tsa: 35 + (20 x 0.2) = 39 °C
2. Tj:  35 + 39 + 0.2 =  74 °C

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: How is the Heat sink sized and if that is how it is calculated ? What does temperature rise above ambient mean ?